# SQL INSERT bind not working

Tags: php, bind

When I call the function `updatePost($postID, $postTitle, $postContent, $catID)` it calls it but fails on the first line `$stmt = db::connect()->prepare`. I am accessing my database the same way for all other functions but this one is failing. Why?

```
function updatePost($inPostID, $inPostTitle, $inPostContent, $inCatID)
{
    var_dump($stmt);
    $stmt = db::connect()->prepare("UPDATE Posts SET postTitle = ?, postContent = ?, postCatID = ?, WHERE postID = ?");
    var_dump($stmt);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssii', $inPostTitle, $inPostContent, $inPostCatID, $inPostID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `PDO::errorInfo()` -- it should explain the syntax error that Dor Shemer noticed.

Comment: @FrankFarmer I am using mysqli

Comment: then `mysqli_error` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: It isn't going past $stmt = db::connect()->prepare() at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the last comma in your SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Posts SET postTitle = ?, postContent = ?, postCatID = ? WHERE postID = ?
```